# JavaFx WebEngine obter conteudo de um Iframe

Tags: javafx, webengine

Não consigo saber quando um Iframe é alterado

Eu uso um `listener` para saber sempre que a pagina é carregada no WebEngine, contudo este `listener` não consegue saber quando o Iframe é alterado/ carregado.

Existe algum forma de detetar as diferenças/ alterações dentro do `Iframe`

Código:
HTML

`<iframe id="principal" name="principal"</iframe>`

`JavaFx`

```
engine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<State>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue ov, State oldState, State newState) {
        if (newState == State.SUCCEEDED) {
            System.out.println("Location" + engine.getLocation());

            Document doc = engine.getDocument();
            HTMLIFrameElement iframeElement = (HTMLIFrameElement) doc.getElementById("principal");
            Document iframeContentDoc = iframeElement.getContentDocument();
            //Element rootElement = iframeContentDoc.getDocumentElement();
            //System.out.println(rootElement.getTextContent());

            NodeList nodeList = iframeContentDoc.getElementsByTagName("a");
            System.out.println("Total de tabs " + nodeList.getLength());  // <--- Dá 0 porque o Iframe ainda não estava carregado, se esperar um pouco consigo obter a informação, contudo nunca sei quando este Iframe está completamente carregado ou foi alterado

        }

    }

});
```

É possível colocar um `listener` neste componente? Como consigo saber quando carregou ou alterou o conteúdo?

Comment: Parece que você quer fazer `addListener` num `NodeList` ou mesmo num `Document`, mas não vi essas opções nessas interfaces. Você pode observar o conteúdo completo do WebEngine, com o [`documentProperty()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html#documentProperty--) dele. Dê uma olhada na documentação da classe WebEngine, parece ser possível conectar-se ao Javascript da página, para que o Javascript chame código Java, se for possível, talvez você possa pôr um Javascript Listener no seu frame HTML. Se conseguir, responda aqui, seria muito bom essa resposta :D